# Типография возвращает манускрипт, так как шрифты с АNSI-кодировкой не встроены

Tags: шрифты, ansi

Очень надеюсь на помощь.

Типография возвращает манускрипт, так как шрифты с ANSI-кодировкой не встроены в пдф-файл. Только те же шрифты, но с кодировкой H-Identity.

Детали: Документ содержит много рамок, картинок и несколько стандартных шрифтов в кирилице.  PDF создан из Word-документа (Word2003).

Что делать?

Comment: Манускрипт - древний или средневековый рукописный свиток. Что делать? Радоваться.

Comment: Да уж, хотелось бы радоваться. Но,честно говоря, хочется плакать. Сидишь ночами над этим "манускриптом", и вот уже когда цель так близка - какие-то технические глупости тормозят весь процесс. Ну неужели в целом мире никто не сталкивался с похожей проблемой?